# Cannot create container for hyperledger service windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I have a docker-compose-cli.yaml file defining 5 services:

```
Starting peer0.org1.example.com ...
Starting peer1.org2.example.com ...
Starting orderer.example.com ...
Starting peer0.org2.example.com ...
Starting peer0.org1.example.com ...
```

Running the command

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d
```

Result in:

```
Creating peer1.org2.example.com ... error
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ...
Creating peer1.org2.example.com ...
Creating peer0.org2.example.com ...
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... error
Creating peer1.org1.example.com ...

ERROR: for peer1.org2.example.com  Cannot start service peer1.org2.example.com: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint peer1.org2.example.com (9Creating peer0.org2.example.com ... error
r

ERROR: for peer0.org1.example.com  Cannot start service peer0.org1.example.com: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint peer0.org1.example.com (aCreating orderer.example.com ... error


Creating peer1.org1.example.com ... error
9b374fc4dc75a62ccdf3b1e5e99c87996941547e67da0adc45958f20d464501): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:9053:tcp:172.18.0.4:7053: input/output error

ERROR: for orderer.example.com  Cannot start service orderer.example.com: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint orderer.example.com (fca3fa13c583f0e7b4411476d1519d09826522da796585312e5a34417b0bc5ed): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:7050:tcp:172.18.0.5:7050: input/output error

ERROR: for peer1.org1.example.com  Cannot start service peer1.org1.example.com: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint peer1.org1.example.com (160f6ca079292769e9b24ddad849c9282c56eed975eb5a287d1431b335cced8a): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:8053:tcp:172.18.0.2:7053: input/output error

ERROR: for peer1.org1.example.com  Cannot start service peer1.org1.example.com: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint peer1.org1.example.com (160f6ca079292769e9b24ddad849c9282c56eed975eb5a287d1431b335cced8a): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:8053:tcp:172.18.0.2:7053: input/output error

ERROR: for peer1.org2.example.com  Cannot start service peer1.org2.example.com: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint peer1.org2.example.com (9c22e5e2029edb8faab4297d6f94c03fc302ed9d55436f7b1282824e9d26dbd6): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:10053:tcp:172.18.0.2:7053: input/output error

ERROR: for orderer.example.com  Cannot start service orderer.example.com: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint orderer.example.com (fca3fa13c583f0e7b4411476d1519d09826522da796585312e5a34417b0bc5ed): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:7050:tcp:172.18.0.5:7050: input/output error

ERROR: for peer0.org1.example.com  Cannot start service peer0.org1.example.com: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint peer0.org1.example.com (a89f0f67fd4fbfc62cfc9ec1b44b587bbb332c27bc4a1dd7f05e67cf17317d37): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:7053:tcp:172.18.0.3:7053: input/output error

ERROR: for peer0.org2.example.com  Cannot start service peer0.org2.example.com: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint peer0.org2.example.com (99b374fc4dc75a62ccdf3b1e5e99c87996941547e67da0adc45958f20d464501): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:9053:tcp:172.18.0.4:7053: input/output error
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I tried to remove the containers using

docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml down
docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml stop

but nothing worked.Do you know why?
Also I think when i run the command up it creates the containers but the services are probably not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks similar to https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1038
The solution seems to be to restart Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn off the Experimental feature in docker settings and everything should work as expected.

[image]